# How to make only my first letter of my first paragraph Drop Cap without changing all next paragraphs with drop caps?

Tags: adobe-indesign, character-styles

I am struggling with Drop Caps and character styles. When I try to make my 1st letter of my 1st paragraph in my body text style Drop Cap, all other paragraphs a beginning with Drop Cap.
How can I do it only for the 1st letter, maybe with character and nested styles?

Answer (score 1):

You need two paragraph styles: one with Drop Cap, one without(let's call it "Body text").
I recommend setting the one with Drop Caps with Next Style: "Body text".

[image]